# How to execute commands, after exiting ADB shell?

Tags: shell

I'm coding a script to automate an application configuration export process.

```
adb shell
...
<open app menu>
<open app settings>
<save app backup>
...
exit
```

The problem is: after saving the backup I want to pull the file to my computer, using this:

```
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Backups/ ~/Documents/phone
```

Although, I can't figure out how to execute this command, after exiting `adb shell`. It seems like commands after `exit` are ignored:

```
adb shell
...
<open app menu>
<open app settings>
<save app backup>
...
exit
adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Backups/ ~/Documents/phone
```

Maybe, this is an issue I should addres to the "Unix & Linux" community, but I decided to try here first.

Comment: Instead of writing the backup to file(s) write them to `stdout` and execute the command using `adb exec-out ... > localfile`. Then the file will be executed on the phone and the output will be written to your PC disk.

Comment: works fine to me.. try a second terminal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write your script a little different:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb shell <<EOF
...
<open app menu>
<open app settings>
<save app backup>
...

EOF

adb pull /storage/emulated/0/Backups/ ~/Documents/phone
```

All between `<<EOF` and the `EOF` standing separately at the start of its own line is run in `adb shell`, all outside is run on your local machine. Note: no `exit` needed.

Comment: The syntax used is an "heredoc". I strongly recommend reading on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-heredoc-to-a-file-in-bash-script. O.P. didn't post the real contents of the script, which may or may not contain variable names supposed to be used in the adb shell, or outside, and that question there contains information about the syntax and other things to note.

Comment: Good point, yes – I didn't get on the name. However, I use HEREDOC a lot, and just verified it again now: other than the top answer there suggests, variables are interpreted inside HEREDOC (tried the given example, like `foo=FOOBAR\ncat <<EOF\necho this is ${foo}\nEOF`, and it printed "This is FOOBAR"). And yes, as in the example, I use Bash; worked with `cat` as well as with `adb shell`. Never blindly believe without verification, even answers upvoted like that one ;) What however does NOT work: setting the var inside the HEREDOC will have no effect of "afterwards".